# Gather Full GC count from remote machine via ssh with Shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a file of server list, and all the servers in it are authorized to the machine which I have logged on. I want to gather Full GC count of all servers from file `/some/path/gc.log` with Shell. How can I do this?
**servers.txt**:

```
192.168.1.101 root
192.168.1.102 root
192.168.1.103 root
192.168.1.104 root
192.168.1.105 root
```

**What done so far**:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
    ip=$(echo $line | cut -f1 -d ' ')
    user=$(echo $line | cut -f2 -d ' ')

    # how to log on remote server and get Full GC count from /some/path/gc.log

done < "servers.txt"
```

**Part of gc.log**:

```
0.756: [Full GC (System) 0.756: [CMS: 0K->1696K(204800K), 0.0347096 secs] 11488K->1696K(252608K), [CMS Perm : 10328K->10320K(131072K)], 0.0347949 secs] [Times: user=0.06 sys=0.00, real=0.05 secs]  
1.728: [GC 1.728: [ParNew: 38272K->2323K(47808K), 0.0092276 secs] 39968K->4019K(252608K), 0.0093169 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs]  
2.642: [GC 2.643: [ParNew: 40595K->3685K(47808K), 0.0075343 secs] 42291K->5381K(252608K), 0.0075972 secs] [Times: user=0.03 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that you want a text report of total GC for each host where total GC is defined the number of lines in the file `gc.log` on which the word `Full` appears.  In that case, use:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read host user
do
    echo "Total GC for $host is $(ssh "$user@$host" "grep 'Full' /path/to/gc.log | wc -l")."
done < "servers.txt"
```

This produces output like:

```
Total GC for 192.168.1.101 is 3.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but "total GC" means how many times, in the `gc.log` each line is one time of GC, I just want get the Full GC count:)

Comment: @Bob.Z OK.  That is much easier.  Answer updated to count the number of lines in `gc.log`.

Comment: I‘m afraid you have misunderstood me, please see my GC log, there are three lines, and consisting of one time Full GC and two times common GC, what I need is just to count Full GC :)

Comment: @Bob.Z OK.  The third revision is up: it reports on the number of lines in `gc.log` that contain the word `Full`.

Answer (score 0):

1- use `sshpass` and `ssh`

```
sshpass -p <password> ssh <user>@<ip> 'cat /some/path/gc.log'
```

Then do whatever you want

2- Use **Expect** Script

Comment: I want to count how many times of Full GC  JVM did, can you edit your answer? :)

Comment: what do you mean by "how many time of full GC JVM did"? please edit your question and give me a specific example.